# In codeigniter, I created static page but still I am getting only Index.php Welcome Message

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

I have installed **CodeIgniter_2.1.3**  and running in

- Windows 7
- Wamp Server 2.1
- PHP 5.3.5
- Apache 2.2.17

I followed this  [Codeignitor Static Pages Tutorial](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html) link provided in Codeignitor.

I created, file at **application/controllers/pages.php** with the following code.

```
<?php class Pages extends CI_Controller 
{

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {

        if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

    }
}
?>
```

and then I created the header at **application/views/templates/header.php** with code as below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $title ?> - CodeIgniter 2 Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CodeIgniter 2 Tutorial</h1>
```

and then i created a footer at **application/views/templates/footer.php** with the following code:

```
<strong>&copy; 2011</strong>    
</body>
</html>
```

and then when i called `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/pages/view/home`

I got this as output

> Welcome to CodeIgniter!
>
> The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by
>   CodeIgniter.
>
> If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:
>   application/views/welcome_message.php
>
> The corresponding controller for this page is found at:
>   application/controllers/welcome.php
>
> If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should
>   start by reading the User Guide.

instead of getting the home.php with appended header.php and footer.php.

I suspect this is because of some wrong settings in either in codeignitor config or in php config or apache server config.

Comment: Why dont you try to go at `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php`

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/ << best CI starter tutorials bar none. Start at one and work your way through.

Comment: thax. i can enter every pages  now.i just set the base_uel blank.and i set index_page as index.php.and i used codeigniter form functions now .

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling like this `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/`, then you have to remove **default controller** from your `routes.php`. It should be empty. By default it is set up with welcome controller.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "" // Replace with your default controller;
```

routes.php will be inside **config folder**.

Comment: thax. i can enter every pages  now.i just set the base_uel blank.and i set index_page as index.php.and i used codeigniter form functions now .

Answer (score 0):

go to application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
```

Hope this helps you
Then go to

```
/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/pages/view
```

Comment: thax. i can enter every pages  now.i just set the base_uel blank.and i set index_page as index.php.and i used codeigniter form functions now .